# read posts made by facebook apps on user's wall/news feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there a way via facebook api call or FQL to get the posts made by facebook apps on user's wall.

**e.g.** user reads an article on "Washington Post Social Reader" app and that appears on the user's wall under Recent Activity.

This does not show up in *me/feed* or *me/posts* or *me/home*.
I read documentation on subscribing to Real Time Updates but that did not provide help on this  matter.

Answer (score 0):

To get activity similar to "Social Reader" you will need to use the following endpoint

`/me/news.reads` with `user_actions.news` permission

An example response

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "10100213573074777", 
      "from": {
        "name": "Philippe Harewood", 
        "id": "13608786"
      }, 
      "start_time": "2011-11-22T22:24:40+0000", 
      "end_time": "2011-11-22T22:24:40+0000", 
      "publish_time": "2011-11-22T22:24:40+0000", 
      "application": {
        "name": "Washington Post Social Reader", 
        "namespace": "wpsocialreader", 
        "id": "225771117449558"
      }, 
      "data": {
        "article": {
          "id": "10150354603148014", 
          "url": "https://fb.trove.com/fbwapolabs/me/channels/67284/content/hLt5k", 
          "type": "article", 
          "title": "Tom Brady May Have Gone Blind"
        }
      }, 
      "type": "news.reads", 
      "no_feed_story": false, 
      "likes": {
        "count": 0, 
        "can_like": true, 
        "user_likes": false
      }, 
      "comments": {
        "count": 0, 
        "can_comment": true, 
        "comment_order": "chronological"
      }
    },
```